# Python: Count nodes of tree

Tags: python

Actually, I'm writing a method which returns the size of a tree:

```
def size(self):
    count = 0
    hasLeft, hasRight = self.left is not None, self.right is not None
    if hasLeft:
        count += self.left.size()
    if hasRight:
        count += self.right.size()
    if (hasLeft or hasRight) and self.root_value is not None:
        count += 1
    return count
```

The method works, but only for interior nodes :(
I'm sure there must be a very easy solution to get the size of the tree...but how?
Example:
If I call:

```
tree=Tree_Class(2,Tree_Class(1,Tree_Class(3),Tree_Class(20)),Tree_Class(13,Tree_Class(33),Tree_Class(39)))
tree.size()
```

The desired output is: 7

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you should also add the code for `Tree_Class` to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your statement `if (hasLeft or hasRight) and self.root_value is not None:` --- this check is wrong, it only `+=1` if the node is not a leaf. When `size` is called, this node must be valid (according to your logic), and therefore `count` should always `+= 1`.

A simpler code would look like the following

```
class Tree_Class:
    def __init__(self, t, left=None, right=None):
        self.root_value = t
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def size(self):
        count = 1
        if self.left:
            count += self.left.size()
        if self.right:
            count += self.right.size()
        return count
```

And the results:

```
>>> tree=Tree_Class(2,Tree_Class(1,Tree_Class(3),Tree_Class(20)),Tree_Class(13,Tree_Class(33),Tree_Class(39)))
>>> tree.size()
7
```

Comment: Your observation is right. Thanks a lot...I really didn't see the error.